# invite/install iOS app with custom action

Tags: ios, app-store, ios9, deep-linking

I am building a group IM app (like GroupMe), and I want to allow users to invite new users to the app by adding them to a group, so when the new user installs and opens the app, they are automatically added to the group.

I have most of this implemented, but I cannot figure out how to pass data to the installation so that I can add the new user to the group.

Is it possible to trigger a custom action upon installation?

Right now I'm texting invite URLs that forward the user to the App Store:

`http://appstore.com/appname/appname`

If I add parameters to the end of it, how do I retrieve them in the app code?

I have been researching but maybe I'm just looking for the wrong thing. I found "deep linking" frameworks like http://applinks.org/ but this doesn't seem to help with custom invites.

Comment: found a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955798/ios-app-store-pass-parameters-in-store-download-link

Comment: Ended up using this library https://branch.io/ love it